# Found mold on the baseboard behind the bed

Tags: wood, mold, baseboard

Just found mold behind the bedframe on the baseboard. I am honestly scared right now as my toddler has been sleeping in the room for the past 3 months.

The room was insulated from exterior with cellulose and the single pane windows were replaced with dual pane last year.

Can someone help me to figure out how bad this is? Also, any instructions on how to get rid of it and next steps?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/usdUweN]

Comment: There are 541 [tag:mold] questions on this site, did you look at any of them? I'm 99.99999% sure you'll find your answers there. You determine _if_ it's mold by having it tested. You'll also find out if it's a harmless mold or something to actually be concerned about. Most of those 541 questions also include suggestions on how to clean it up. Oh, and mold is all around you 24/7/365 - live your life in a hermetically sealed bubble or recognize that most of it isn't as bad as the media would have you believe.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like it's from spillage, such as milk, juice or food.

If its confined to that area, then just clean it and keep an eye on it. Use soap and water.